# floatThead affecting height of header

Tags: jquery, html, css, html-table

I have a html page with a table where I use this JQuery plugin:  http://mkoryak.github.io/floatThead/

My header shrinks when floatThead comes into play. This is my code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Optional theme -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.floatThead.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="no-rank.css" />
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
var target = $('body');
var totalHeight;
$(document).ready(function() { totalHeight = $(document).height();
    var $table = $('table.header-fixed');
    $table.floatThead();
  });
</script>
  <table class='header-fixed main-table'>
    <thead>
    <tr class="LeaderboardHeader">
      <th class="ranktitle">  </th>
      <th class="nametitle"> Name  </th>
      <th class="steptitle">  </th>
      <th class="visualtitle">  Steps  </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="rank"> 1 </td>
      <td class="name"> <img src="img3.jpg" /> <span> User User1</span> </td>
      <td class="steps"> 3000 </td>
      <td class="visual">
        <div class="progress" style="opacity: 1">
          <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-info" style="width: 1000%">
              <span class="sr-only">20%</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="empty"><td></td></tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="rank"> 2 </td>
      <td class="name"> <img src="img1.jpg" /> <span> Another User</span> </td>
      <td class="steps"> 2759 </td>
      <td class="visual">
        <div class="progress " style="opacity: .95">
          <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-info" style="width: 95%">
              <span class="sr-only">20%</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="empty"><td></td></tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="rank"> 3 </td>
      <td class="name"> <img src="img2.jpg" /> <span> AFirstName LastName</span> </td>
      <td class="steps"> 2359 </td>
      <td class="visual">
        <div class="progress " style="opacity: 0.85">
          <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-info" style="width: 85%">
              <span class="sr-only">20%</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="empty"><td></td></tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="rank"> 4 </td>
      <td class="name"> <img src="img3.jpg" /> <span> Mohammed Ali</span> </td>
      <td class="steps"> 2000 </td>
      <td class="visual">
        <div class="progress " style="opacity: .8">
          <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-info" style="width: 80%">
              <span class="sr-only">80%</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="empty"><td></td></tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="rank"> 5 </td>
      <td class="name"> <img src="img4.jpg" /> <span> Random Name</span> </td>
      <td class="steps"> 1808 </td>
      <td class="visual">
        <div class="progress" style="opacity: 0.7">
          <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-info" style="width: 70%">
              <span class="sr-only">20%</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <!-- More rows -->
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

I have actually removed most of the html code. Basically there are a lot more rows where I put `<!-- More rows here -->`. That's all.

This is my css:

```
body{
  background-color: #E0F2F7;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #333333;
  font-size: 2em;
}

table.main-table td.rank, table.main-table th.ranktitle{ border-left: solid 1px #CCCCCC; }
table.main-table td.visual, table.main-table th.visualtitle{ border-right: solid 1px #CCCCCC; }

td { border-bottom: solid 1px #CCCCCC; }

@media screen and (min-width: 1280px){
  table.main-table td.rank, table.main-table th.ranktitle{ border-left: solid 2px #CCCCCC; }
  table.main-table td.visual, table.main-table th.visualtitle{ border-right: solid 2px #CCCCCC; }
  td { border-bottom: solid 2px #CCCCCC; }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1960px){
  table.main-table td.rank, table.main-table th.ranktitle{ border-left: solid 3px #CCCCCC; }
  table.main-table td.visual, table.main-table th.visualtitle{ border-right: solid 3px #CCCCCC; }
  td { border-bottom: solid 3px #CCCCCC; }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 2560px){
  table.main-table td.rank, table.main-table th.ranktitle{ border-left: solid 4px #CCCCCC; }
  table.main-table td.visual, table.main-table th.visualtitle{ border-right: solid 4px #CCCCCC; }
  td { border-bottom: solid 4px #CCCCCC; }
}

html, body{
  height: 100%;
}

table.main-table{
  width: 98%;
  margin: auto;
  height: 100%;
}

table.main-table tr{
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
  margin-bottom: 1%;
}

table.main-table tr, table.main-table td{
  min-width: 10%;
}

thead{
  width: 100%;
  height: 15%;
}

tbody{
  height: 85%;
  width: 100%;
}

table.main-table, table.main-table th{
  text-align: center;
}

table.main-table tr.LeaderboardHeader{
  height: 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #CCCCCC 0%, #999999 100%);
  font-weight: normal;
  margin: auto;
}

table.main-table th{
  padding: 0.25% 0;
  height: 100%;
}

table.main-table td{
  padding: 0.25% 0;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #FFFFFF 0%, #FFFFFF 100%);
}

table.main-table th.ranktitle{
  text-align: right;
  width: 3%;
  padding-right: 0.5%;
}

table.main-table th.nametitle{
  width: 45%;
}

table.main-table th.visualtitle{
  width: 37%;
  text-align: left;
  padding-right: 2%;
}

table.main-table th.steptitle{
  width: 15%;
  padding-right: 2%;
}

table.main-table td.rank{
  text-align: right;
  width: 3%;
  padding-right: 0.5%;
  text-align: right;
}

table.main-table td.name{
  text-align: left;
}

table.main-table td.name span{
  padding-left: 5%;
}

table.main-table td.steps{
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 2%;
}

table.main-table td.visual{
    padding-right: 2%;
}

table.main-table td.name img{
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
}

.progress{
  margin: auto;
  height: 60px;
}

/* Shadows */

td{
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #555555;
}

tr.empty{
  opacity: 0;
  height: 100%;
  }

tr.empty td, div{
  height: 16px;
}
```

I'm sure the problem is with my css hence why I included all the css but after 1 hour of debugging the bug still eludes me.

Thank you to whoever goes through all of that css code.

EDIT: Here is a jsFiddle with the above code: http://jsfiddle.net/m3omd6wL/1/

Comment: Do you have a clearfix on the parent? If you are floating all the elements in the header it will collapse. [Micro Clearfix](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/)

Comment: The only thing inside the header is  `<tr> <td> </td> ... </tr>`. Just a row with a bunch of cells in it. They aren't floated but I do know that rows and cells in a table behave differently from inline or block.

Comment: I don't have experience with that plugin but I would suggest it is floating the elements which is causing the container to collapse. Try adding that clearfix class to the parent containers.

Comment: Didn't work. I googled clearfix and applied it to the parent <td>, <tr> and <thead>. It didn't change anything.

Comment: Bummer, well could you create a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) of your code, then will be able to take a look.

Comment: @Guy Done. Here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/m3omd6wL/1/

Comment: The header doesn't shrink for me?

Comment: So when you scroll down does the header stay at the top? That's what the script is supposed to do. Keep the header floating on the top. It does that but when you scroll down the header shrinks.

Comment: Ah yea, can see it. Will take a look later for you

Answer (score 1):

Please try this. It's worked for me

```
  var $table = $('table.table-wages');
  $table.floatThead({
    scrollingTop: 0,
    useAbsolutePositioning: false,
    scrollContainer: function($table){
      return $table.closest('.table-wages-container');
     }
  });
  // try to resize table thead. tr
  $(".size-row,.floatThead-col").css("height", '48px');
```